pino transports in aws lambda
I am trying to setup a logger in my aws lambda functions using pino with multiple transports. pino supports flushing the logger, but unfortunately, this doesn't guarantee that the worker threads will have finished processing all the messages. I have tried running logger[symbols.streamSym].flushSync() at the end of each function, but confirmed that many messages are lost if the lambda doesn't run long enough. By executing the lambda a few more times, I can get the messages to process.
I was wondering if there is any mechanism to wait for the logger to finish processing all log messages sent, before ending the lambda execution?
